# I keep running into this error: Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, mern

Here is my code with all of the work arounds that I have tried.

```
 // import * as firebase from 'firebase'; //work around
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //work around (works?)
// import 'firebase/compat/auth'; //work around 
// import 'firebase/firestore'; //work around 
// import 'firebase/firestore'; //work around
// import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'; //work around
// import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
// import firebase from '@firebase/app'; //work around 
// require('firebase/auth'); //work around
// import firebase from 'firebase/app'; //work around
// import 'firebase/auth'; //work around 
// console.log(firebase.auth); //word around
// import firebase from 'firebase/app';
// import 'firebase/firestore'; //work around
// import 'firebase/auth';  //work around
// import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app'; //work around 
// import {getFirestore, collection, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore/lite'; //work around 
// import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'; //work around 

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBYZCeQfHboP-zEDyNGyMODEfx33RiQmTg",
    authDomain: "graphqlmernstack.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "graphqlmernstack",
    storageBucket: "graphqlmernstack.appspot.com",
    // messagingSenderId: "165123567996",
    appId: "1:165123567996:web:6c808a04288956d188f4f9",
    measurementId: "G-6G4BVK9FQZ"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
// const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //work around
// const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //work around 
// const db = getFirestore(firebase); //work around 
// const auth = getAuth(firebase); //work around

// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);


// console.log(auth);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried almost everything I have found to get the code working as you can see in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.auth is not a function

You'll need to import the auth compat library:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

Also see the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) for the v9 Firebase SDK and later.

Comment: I used import 'firebase/compat/auth'; before and it gives me the error 'firebase' is not defined no-undef –

Comment: An `import` should not give you that error. It really helps if you edit your question to show just a single thing you tried: the one that you thought should've worked, and the error you get with that.